# How can I increase my vertical jump?

Tags: sports, physiology, physical-therapy, physique

I am a 5"6' guy who takes active participation in football (soccer) and other activities like gym and calisthenics.The problem is due to my short stature,I need a higher jump to compensate the height difference with the rival player(eg like header).Is there any specific training I can do to maximize my vertical jump and reach? (for eg. I also wish to increase my reach as to grab a bar high up vertically.)

Comment: http://msuathletics.ru/books/bible/vert_jump_bible.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You should perform a combination of heavy weight training (squats, lunges, calves with legpress) and explosive training (box jumps, sprints) to increase your fast power and improve muscle coordination